# Listbox - How do I enumerate the contents of a WPF listbox properly? WPF- VB.Net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listbox

I needed a listbox with a String item, followed by 2 buttons for each row.
This I got working after ploughing through some answers and tutorials on WPF listboxes on here.

Now I want to programmatically modify the text on the buttons on certain rows, but cannot seem to access them.

I thought if I enumerated each item as ItemCollection in PListbox.items I could access them, but PListbox.items claims to return a string, not an ItemCollection as I expected.

Here is my XAML markup for the listbox....

```
<Window x:Class="PrinterChooser"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Gatekeeper2018"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="PrinterChooser" Height="450" Width="500" Background="#FF005A9E" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="#FF669CC5" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#FF337BB1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="5,5,0,0">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBEE6FD"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFC4E5F6"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF2C628B"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFBCDDEE"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF245A83"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFADB2B5"/>
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="#FF838383"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#19f39611"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#19000000"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="PListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Background="#FF005A9E" Foreground="White" AlternationCount="2">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="175"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="175"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding}" />
                    <Button x:Name="SessionButton" Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click" Template="{DynamicResource ButtonControlTemplate1}" Foreground="White">Add Printer this session</Button>
                    <Button x:Name="AllocateButton" Grid.Column="2" Click="Button_Click" Template="{DynamicResource ButtonControlTemplate1}" Foreground="White">Add Printer always</Button>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

And my test-code to look for the buttons -

```
    Public Sub DisplayList(ByVal pString As String)
    Dim dum As String
    Dim plist As New List(Of String)
    For Each printer As String In pString.Split(","c)
        If printer IsNot "" Then
            plist.Add(printer)
        End If
    Next
    PListBox.ItemsSource = plist
    For Each itemcol As ItemCollection In PListBox.Items

        dum = itemcol.GetType.ToString
        MsgBox(dum)

    Next
End Sub
```

PString contains the list of string items for the list (comma separated)
This list displays correctly, and I can handle the events from clicking the buttons just fine. But I need to set the initial state of the buttons (I can do this on click, but not by enumerating the contents of the listbox)

```
    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If sender.Content.contains("always") Then
        If sender.Content.startswith("Add") Then
            sender.Content = "Do not always add printer"
            sender.Foreground = Brushes.Yellow
            'Datacontext contains PrinterName as a String
            HandleMap(sender.Datacontext.ToString, True)
        Else
            sender.Content = "Add Printer always"
            sender.Foreground = Brushes.White
            'Datacontext contains PrinterName as a String
            HandleMap(sender.Datacontext.ToString, False)
        End If
    Else
        If sender.Content.startswith("Add") Then
            sender.Content = "Remove Printer this session"
            sender.Foreground = Brushes.Yellow
        Else
            sender.Content = "Add Printer this Session"
            sender.Foreground = Brushes.White
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Looking for ui controls and setting properties ( the winforms way ) is not the usual way to work with wpf. Instead, mostly people bind and work with the data in a viewmodel instead. You then don't have to go find a control, it finds the property it's bound to. MVVM.

Comment: For Each printer As String In pString.Split(","c) . You say PString is a list of string each with a comma (guess that's pString) but you Split does't work for a list.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, that part works fine.
PString is a String, like "A15-Lsr,A16-Lst,A16-Col" which is made into a list of String. which is the itemsSource for the ListBox

Comment: I think (looking at some very confusing tutorials) that Andy's suggestion is correct. Just trying to get my head around how I can do that now.

Comment: Maybe these'll help you get your head around the very basics of MVVM and get you started. I use c# but you could put the code through an online converter.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31915.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-1.aspx   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32164.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-2.aspx

Comment: Thank you. Will give those a read now and experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Andy (in the comments of the question).
I now have my code working and am able to update the buttons at will.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_ListBox_Test_mvvm"
    xmlns:VisualBasic="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic;assembly=Microsoft.VisualBasic" xmlns:My="clr-namespace:WPF_ListBox_Test_mvvm.My" x:Class="MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="175"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="175"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding AllocatedButton}" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding SessionButton}" Click="Button_Click_1"/>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="myListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="399" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="466" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxTemplate}">



    </ListBox>
    <Button Content="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="657,364,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button Content="Alter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="657,326,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Alter"/>

</Grid>
```

Test Harness behind.

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Class MainWindow
Public PrinterItems As ObservableCollection(Of PrinterItem)
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    PrinterItems = New ObservableCollection(Of PrinterItem)
    PrinterItems.Clear()
    myListBox.DataContext = PrinterItems
    myListBox.ItemsSource = PrinterItems

    PrinterItems.Add(New PrinterItem("A16", "Add this Session", "Add always"))
    PrinterItems.Add(New PrinterItem("A22", "Add this Session", "Add always"))
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    MsgBox(sender.ToString)
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Alter(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    For Each item As PrinterItem In PrinterItems
        If item.Name.Equals("A22") Then
            item.SessionButton = "Woot"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
End Class

Public Class PrinterItem
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub

Public _name As String
Public _session As String
Public _allocate As String
Public Sub New(ByVal n As String, sButton As String, aButton As String)
    _name = n
    _session = sButton

    _allocate = aButton
End Sub

Public Property Name As String
    Get
        Return _name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _name = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property

Public Property SessionButton As String
    Get
        Return _session
    End Get
    Set(value As String)

        _session = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property

Public Property AllocatedButton As String
    Get
        Return _allocate
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _allocate = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property

Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return _name
End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the name like 'PListBox' and then

```
    For Each listb As ListBoxItem In PListBox.Items

    Next
```

you can the loop through them. you can also set a 'tag' on each of the rows to reference them individually.

'tag = "Plistbox_item1"'

```
        If listb.Tag = "Plistbox_item1" Then
        'do something cool.
        End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  However it doesn't work.
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem'.'

This is what is confusing me.  When I type Plistbox.Items  Visual Studio says it returns an ItemCollection, but when I try that, it gives the exception above.  If I don't specify the type,  (for each item in Plistbox.items) it works, and each item is a String (containing the printer name)  I can't seem to access the buttons on the row.

Comment: f you want to use this, you have to assign a Command to your button and use it as command parameter. further readings here... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-enable-a-command